# How to generate Swift files from proto that contain imports?

Tags: swift, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto, grpc-swift

Let's say I have a .proto file located in /home/me/project/first/a.proto.
And another proto file located in /home/me/project/second/b.proto.
I want to be able to generate swift files from these proto.
b.proto uses an import as follows:

```
import "first/a.proto"
```

Now I try to run:

```
protoc -I=/home/me/project --swift_out=swiftout /home/me/project/second/b.proto
```

I get an error message which says that

```
first/a.proto: File not found.
```

How to properly use the import?